# Map to Union Case constructor without pattern match

Tags: f#

I have a union type `CustomerEvent` like this:

```
type CustomerRegisteredEvent = { CompanyName: string }
type CustomerDeletedEvent = { DeletedOn: DateTimeOffset }

type CustomerEvent =
  | CustomerRegistered of CustomerRegisteredEvent
  | CustomerDeleted of CustomerDeletedEvent
```

I also have a `map` function like this:

```
let map (input: Events.IEvent): CustomerEvent =
  match input with
  | :? Events.IEvent<CustomerRegisteredEvent> as event ->
      CustomerRegistered(event.Data)
  | :? Events.IEvent<CustomerDeletedEvent> as event ->
      CustomerDeleted(event.Data)
```

As can be seen, both paths are almost the same except for the constructor of the union case.

Can this been written in a more generic way - maybe even without having to use pattern matching?

Comment: You could probably do this with reflection. Is that an approach you'd consider?

Comment: Yes, reflection would be ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty, but I think this does what you want:

```
open FSharp.Reflection

let getCaseMap<'t> () =
    FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<'t>)
        |> Seq.map (fun unionCase ->
            let typ =
                let property =
                    unionCase.GetFields() |> Seq.exactlyOne
                property.PropertyType
            let create data =
                FSharpValue.MakeUnion(unionCase, [| data |])
                    :?> 't
            typ.Name, create)
        |> Map

let caseMap = getCaseMap<CustomerEvent> ()

let map (input: Events.IEvent) =
    let typ =
        input.GetType().GenericTypeArguments
            |> Seq.exactlyOne
    let data =
        let property =
            input.GetType().GetProperty("Data")
        property.GetValue(input)
    caseMap.[typ.Name] data
```

This uses reflection to avoid pattern matching, doing a map lookup instead to find the correct union case directly from the given event's type. It assumes the DU follows a rigid pattern, so there's no error handling.

Comment: Replaced the code from the question and everything still seems to work. Thanks!